# knitr compilation fails with R error message and babel package

Tags: r, latex, knitr, babeljs

Have a look at this minimal example. It works fine when the babel package is commented out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\begin{document}
<<>>=
abc() #a non-existing function
@

\end{document}
```

With the babel package I get this error. The error depends on the language as well. No error with english, french or italian. Error with dutch, german or danish. The problem seems to occur with languages that have umlauts (ä, ö, ...)

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.67 ...\#\# Error: could not find function "abc"}
                                                  }\end{kframe}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

Comment: You'll have to tell us what your function does because this isn't exactly reproducible.

Comment: Reproduces here, though I don't know what the problem is.  Maybe poke in the tex output files and see what the difference is there?  Depending what you find, perhaps ask to migrate to tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Aaron I think your explanation is correct. I noticed that problem long time ago, and have fixed it [just now](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/e9a5e85c829). Thierry, please test the [latest version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) on Github.

Comment: @Yihui the problem is solved with the latest version on GitHub. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
```

R and LaTeX can have some weird text encoding problems when using non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: The third one by itself is sufficient on my system.

Comment: @Aaron cool, I usually keep the first two around to fix other text problems from including SAS output.

Comment: @EllisValentiner this is a good workaround with the current CRAN version of knitr.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer (for that, see @EllisValentiner's), but an explanation:

Here's a minimal reproducible tex document.  Seems to be something to do with the `"`, so your guess about umlaut seems right on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\begin{document}
"}
\end{document}
```

@baptiste noticed that babel is making it an active character, what it seems to be doing is "swallowing" the following character to see if it should put an umlaut on it; if so, it does, and if not, it prints the character normally.  However, if the next character is a `}`, it's getting added to the code that figures out what to do, which then complains about having an extra `}`.

So this minimal example works, I think because it's processing both `{` and the `}` in the babel code, and so the braces line up properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\begin{document}
"{"}
\end{document}
```

Not sure if this is a babel bug, or if you're just not supposed to use `"` for quotes when using babel.  That seems reasonable except in the case where you're using a `tt` family, which is when this problem first arose.

Someone more curious than I should feel free to post this behavior as a question on tex.stackexchange; if you do so, leave a link here so we can find it.

Comment: I see this in the tex log file: "Package babel Info: Making " an active character", which suggests a reason why a double quote becomes a umlaut.

Comment: Nice find, baptiste.  That explains my confusion at the behavior I found. (See upcoming edit).

Comment: I think this has clearly explained the problem, and should be accepted as the answer, with a further note that the problem has been fixed in the devel version of knitr.

Comment: Thanks for finding this and fixing it so quickly, Yihui!  I like your fix of replacing `"` with `"{}`.  On another note, I've been meaning to try knitr for ages, and when I recently did, it was a very pleasant surprise to find out that I can usually just rebuild my Sweave docs with knitr, with minor changes at most.  Bought your book too and am looking forward to learning more about what it can do.  Thanks for your good work!